# Answer edit rejected, but answer is technically incorrect without my edit

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, rejected-edits, wrong-answers

Yesterday, I made this edit to an answer, as I ended up running into the exact same issue myself.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7380622

The answer helped me fix my problem, but was missing a critical component (the scenario is not unique to me, though it may be relatively uncommon). Without my addition, the accepted answer simply does not work in 100% of cases. My edit makes the answer whole.

Please help me understand why the edit was rejected. I realize I could have posted a comment, but if the original author of the answer never updated their post, it would have remained incorrect.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a radical change because it changes the meaning, whether it was wrong before and right now or not. Leave a comment, and possibly a competing answer, if there isn't one for you to upvote already.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I understand now. I will leave a comment for the original answering party. Would it be acceptable in the future to add to the answer with an additional code block that explains the scenario, rather than editing the existing one?

Comment: No, just add/upvote a competing answer which is right. And consider downvoting the wrong answer, as well as commenting how and why to improve it. (In case you already suggested an extensive edit which was rejected, you might even link that too.)